# Ubuntu desktop 16 lost i915 drivers after kernel upgrade

Tags: drivers, kernel, i915

i have 2 systems both are exactly the same hardware.
on 1st box i installed efi Ubuntu desktop 16.04.4 then upgraded to 4.15.0-43-generic and all works as expected. (i can see my i2c bus\devices )

2nd box was already installed with bios Ubuntu desktop 16.04 kernel 4.4.0-71, Ubuntu dident detected i2c bus\devices correctly.
so first step i changed the boot from bios to efi boot loader.
system boot ok but still dose not see i2c bus correctly .
2nd step was to upgrade to same kernel as in 1st box 4.15.0-43-generic.
after upgrade to 4.15,  Ubuntu not loading a lot of drivers for example the i915.
Ubuntu also not see the i2c bus at all now (i guess drivers missing )

so why this happen ? same hardware same kernel

how to resolve this ?

Answer (score -1):

so i purged the newly installed kernels and rebooted to the original kernel .

then i found this :
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

and i used this command to upgrade kernel :

```
 sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
```

the kernel upgraded to 4.15.0-43-generic.

now all works great